# RX.Net : Use Retry but log any Exception

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

I am new to RX and have been investigating error handling and the use of Retry; I have the following (yes I know it's not a 'real' unit test but it gives me place to fiddle!!) and was wondering how I go about keeping the Retry but be able to log any Exception?

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

        var source = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
            new Recorded<Notification<long>>(10000000, Notification.CreateOnNext(0L)),
            new Recorded<Notification<long>>(20000000, Notification.CreateOnNext(1L)),
            new Recorded<Notification<long>>(30000000, Notification.CreateOnNext(2L)),
            new Recorded<Notification<long>>(30000001, Notification.CreateOnError<long>(new Exception("Fail"))),
            new Recorded<Notification<long>>(40000000, Notification.CreateOnNext(3L)),
            new Recorded<Notification<long>>(40000000, Notification.CreateOnCompleted<long>())
        );

        source.Retry().Subscribe(
            l => Console.WriteLine($"OnNext {l}"), 
            exception => Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString()), // Would be logging this in production
            () => Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted"));

       scheduler.Start(
            () => source,
            0,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).Ticks);
    }
```

Which results in...

```
OnNext 0
OnNext 1
OnNext 2
OnNext 3
OnCompleted
```

...which is exactly what I want to happen apart from fact I would like to log the Exception which occurs between 2 and 3.

Is there a way to allow the Subscriber to see the Exception in OnError (and log it) and then re-subscribe so it sees 3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could achieve that with this:

```
source
    .Do(_ => { }, exception => Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString()), () => {})
    .Retry()
    .Subscribe(
        l => Console.WriteLine($"OnNext {l}"),
        //      exception => Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString()), // Would be logging this in production
        () => Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted")
    );
```

Just to clarify what's going on here: `OnError` is a terminating signal. If the error reached the subscription, that would terminate the rest of the stream. `.Retry` terminates the subscription, swallows the `OnError`, and then re-subscribes, melding the two subscriptions together. For example look at this:

```
source
    .StartWith(-1)
    .Retry()
    .Subscribe(
        l => Console.WriteLine($"OnNext {l}"),
        () => Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted")
    );
```

Your output would be

```
OnNext -1
OnNext 0
OnNext 1
OnNext 2
OnNext -1
OnNext 3
OnCompleted
```

The `OnNext -1` shows up twice, because it shows up whenever you subscribe (which `Retry` does after the `OnError`.

Your test observable is frankly a bad test. It breaks the "Rx Contract" which is that notifications follow the following pattern:

```
OnNext* (OnCompleted | OnError)?
```

That is, 0 or more `OnNext` notifications, followed by an optional `OnError` or an optional `OnCompleted`. No notifications of any type should follow either an `OnError` or an `OnCompleted`.

Comment: With regard to the the bad test; the result of trying to get a simple example together and failing!! :-( Thank you for the clarification, I hadn't fully appreciated how Retry functioned.

Comment: What I actually have in my application is the hot observable being driven from FromEventPattern. I receive an event containing a byte[], I then Decrypt the byte[], establish the message type and deserialize accordingly; in the Observer.OnNext I carry out an action based on that message. What I don't want to happen is for the stream to terminate if I have any issues in those operations (decryption/serialization etc.). I just want to log the failure and continue on processing. Is that possible?

Comment: "What I don't want to happen is for the stream to terminate" should be "What I don't want to happen is for the subscription to terminate "

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what `.Retry` does. It terminates and resubscribes, but in a transparent manner to downstream subscribers.

Comment: OK, thank you. So Retry is the correct approach but logging any failure is not feasible. Hope I am understanding that correctly!!

Comment: You can log, it just has to be done prior to the Retry.