# Rx Net - Handle errors and resubscribe to observable

Tags: c#, .net, exception, events, system.reactive

I'm planning to replace .Net events with observables. I like the Linq way that every subscriber can filter and transform data in their own way.

Rx by default is disposing the subscription and closing the stream when an unhandled exception is thrown somewhere in the piping (eg inside select, where, subscribe). As a result, any next calls to onNext() will not end up on the subscription because it was disposed by the previous exception, and the listener which was subscribed will not be notified!

With classic .Net events this is not an issue. Every event invocation is independent of any other, meaning that even if a call throws an exception, the next call will have it's own chance to run successfully.

Ideally, I would like to use EventLooperScheduler so any call to onNext will not wait for subscribers to do their job.

I have ended up with the following code so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WriteLine("Main Thread {{THREAD_ID}}");

        RxEvent<int> myEvent = new RxEvent<int>(new EventLoopScheduler());

        IDisposable subscriptionA = myEvent.Stream
            .Where(x =>
            {
                //exception for testing purposes, this could be a null_reference, or a file_not_found, or a webrequest exception
                if (x.EventArgs == 2)
                    throw new ArgumentException();

                return true;
            })
            .Subscribe(x =>
            {
                //exception for testing purposes, this could be a null_reference, or a file_not_found, or a webrequest exception
                //comment out Where() exception to try this one
                if (x.EventArgs == 3)
                    throw new ArgumentException();

                WriteLine($"Subscriber A {{THREAD_ID}} Value: {x.EventArgs}");

                Thread.Sleep(500);
            },
            onError =>
            {
                var ex = onError;
            });

        IDisposable subscriptionB = myEvent.Stream.Subscribe(x =>
        {
            WriteLine($"Subscriber B {{THREAD_ID}} Value: {x.EventArgs}");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        });

        for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            myEvent.Invoke(null, i);
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine("END");
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void WriteLine(string str)
    {
        str = str.Replace("{THREAD_ID}", $"[Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}]");
        System.Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}

public class RxEvent<T>
{
    EventHandler<T> _Event;
    IObservable<EventPattern<T>> _Observable;
    IScheduler _Scheduler;

    public RxEvent()
        : this(CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance)
    {
    }

    public RxEvent(IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        _Scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    public IObservable<EventPattern<T>> Stream
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Observable == null)
                _Observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<T>(h => _Event += h, h => _Event -= h).ObserveOn(_Scheduler);

            return _Observable;
        }
    }

    public void Invoke(object sender, T args)
    {
        _Event?.Invoke(sender, args);
    }
}
```

When the first exception is thrown, Where's implementation catches it and just disposes the subscription. In contrast, when the second exception (inside subscribe) is thrown, no one is handled it, and makes thread to stop.

My question is, is threre any way to handle these situations and keep the subscription alive in order to proccess any upcoming invocations, even if some of them throw an unhandled exception?

In my scenarion I get the following output when the first exception is throw. (when the second exception is throw the thread crashes):

```
Main Thread {[Thread 1]}
END
Subscriber A [Thread 4] Value: 1
Subscriber B [Thread 4] Value: 1
Subscriber B [Thread 4] Value: 2
Subscriber B [Thread 4] Value: 3
Subscriber B [Thread 4] Value: 4
Subscriber B [Thread 4] Value: 5
Subscriber B [Thread 4] Value: 6
Subscriber B [Thread 4] Value: 7
```

Instead I would like to get:

```
Main Thread {[Thread 1]}
END
Subscriber A [Thread 4] Value: 1
Subscriber B [Thread 4] Value: 1
Subscriber B [Thread 4] Value: 2
Subscriber B [Thread 4] Value: 3
Subscriber A [Thread 4] Value: 4
Subscriber B [Thread 4] Value: 4
Subscriber A [Thread 4] Value: 5
Subscriber B [Thread 4] Value: 5
Subscriber A [Thread 4] Value: 6
Subscriber B [Thread 4] Value: 6
Subscriber A [Thread 4] Value: 7
Subscriber B [Thread 4] Value: 7
```

(Value 2 and 3 throws an exception for subscriberA so nothing should be printed)

A relative resource I found is [Rx - can/should I replace .NET events with Observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567899/rx-can-should-i-replace-net-events-with-observables)

Comment: Why not just catch and handle exception yourself? What you propose is just ignore exceptions and that is rarely good way to go.

Comment: I'd like every call to OnNext to run independent of any other. I want to subscribe knowing that I will not lose any message even if some of them fail somewhere in the piping. Of course, I could catch exceptions on my own (at least the obvious exceptions), but I'd like a more robust way.

Comment: The `EventLoopScheduler` does precisely the opposite of what you're asking for.

Comment: By that I mean any call to `.OnNext` **will** wait for subscribers for finish when using `EventLoopScheduler`. Why do you want them to fire immediately? You have to deal with concurrency issues then.

Comment: EventLoopScheduler creates a new thread which serves all calls to .OnNext and the main thread is not waiting for the OnNext to complete. See http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html#EventLoopScheduler

Answer (score 2):

Just one simple rule: no exceptions in explicit Subscribe.

Use `Do` instead, that way you can also use `Retry` after it to restart the subscription.

As shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391092/rx-net-use-retry-but-log-any-exception) answer, there is also an overload of `Do` that takes `OnError` handler:

```
source
    .Do(_ => { 
              throw new SomeException();
        }, 
            exception => Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString()) // log exceptions from source stream,
            () => {})
    .Retry()
    .Subscribe(
        l => Console.WriteLine($"OnNext {l}"),
        //      exception => Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString()), // Would be logging this in production
        () => Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted")
    );
```

You can throw `Do().Retry()` at the end and it will work and you won't miss any notifications. Just remember to dispose the subscriptions, otherwise it will wait for `OnCompleted` signal.